Godot v4.1.3 not allowing export to HTML5, even though I am not using C#
I would like to export my project as a web build, for which I am following the example given in these tutorials: tutorial1 tutorial2. This seems routine enough, but when I try to reproduce this, I get the following messages:

-Exporting to Web is currently not supported in Godot 4 when using C#/.NET. Use Godot 3 to target Web with C#/Mono instead.


-If this project does not use C#, use a non-C# editor build to export the project.

Screenshot of the errors
My project does not use C#. I am not sure what it means with a "non-C# editor build" and could not find anything about it.
Thank you for checking this out.
I am at a loss for what to do. I don't know what a "non-C# editor build" is.

"A non-C# editor build" means the version of Godot that doesn't support .Net, ie https://github.com/godotengine/godot/releases/download/4.2.1-stable/Godot_v4.2.1-stable_win64.exe.zip
